# Ответ из java контроллера в XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно отвечать из java @RestController на XMLHttpRequest из javascript.

```
@ResponseBody                                        
@RequestMapping(value = "/authorization", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String authorization(
        @RequestParam String login,
        @RequestParam String password) {
    System.out.println(login + " " + password);
    return "HelloWorld!";
}
```

**Javascript**

```
formData.append("login", $("#login").val());
formData.append("password", $("#password").val());
formData.append("delete", document.getElementById("deleteCheck").checked);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "authorization",false);
xhr.send(formData);
alert(xhr.responseText);
```

В контроллере я вижу логин и пароль, а в ответе не вижу.

Comment: Сделал так:    @RequestMapping(value = "/authorization", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ToSend authorization(@RequestParam String login,
                                @RequestParam String password){

        ToSend toSend = new ToSend();
        toSend.getCustomers().add(new Customer(login,password));
        toSend.getCustomers().add(new Customer("Customer2","123456"));
        toSend.setMessage("Authorization OK!");
        System.out.println(toSend);

        return toSend;   В ответ HttpStatus 500.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите вернуть JSON, то нужно добавить аннотацию `@ResponseBody` на метод контроллера.

Comment: Это @RestController забыл написать. Не работает...

Comment: Если используется аннотация `@RestController`, писать `@ResponseBody` не нужно, оно автоматически делает все методы аннотированными.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это потому, что вы отправляете в респонсе стринг с текстом "Hello World?". 
Вам нужно создать объект, что-то на подобие DTO, в который вы сетаете возвращаемые в респонсе значения и в `return` передавать его. 
Пример:

```
return new Response(username, password);
```

Но лучше сделать какою-то респонсив обертку, которая будет возвращать статус, сообщения с статуса и сам объект.

Кроме этого нужно подключить `HttpJacksonMapper` и три депенденси `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`.

А 500 ошибка говорит о том, что вы где-то передаете не правильный тип значений.

И почему бы входным параметром не сделать модель с полями username и password и принимать его как `@RequestBody AuthModel request`? А если входных параметров будет 10? Так же проще.

Comment: Насчет депенденси поточнее можно?) Я пробовал Json - не работает 500 ошибка. А HelloWorld и все остальное просто для упрощения сделал.

Comment: @НиколайЕгоров можете здесь посмотреть `https://github.com/dkhodan/REST---JWT-Security---Swagger-UI`, заодно посмотрите конфигурации и депенденси.

Comment: Добавил...Ошибка 500

Comment: можете куда-то полностью залить свой код вместе с конфигурациями? возможно на гит или битбакет, чтобы можно было поставить локально. возможно проблемы где-то в конфигах.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/NikolayEgorov/c25697ad0da41b09b1e1a7d36331a7a0